# I am trying to click a hidden element by making it visible but the code clicks the next visible element

Tags: selenium, hidden

View source of the element is as below, where I am trying to click `Console` under `Alt`. I want to make the element visible using JavaScript. Then I want to click the same element, but doing so is clicking the next visible element (i.e. `Order`).

Please suggest a workaround for this issue.

```
&lt;td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onclick="somthing">
Alt
&lt;/td>
 &lt;div id="somID" name="SomName" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border:">
  &lt;DIV  myonclick="Something">
   Console
  &lt;/DIV>
 &lt;/div>
&lt;td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onclick="Something">
Order
&lt;/td>
 &lt;div id="somID" name="SomName" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border:">
  &lt;DIV  myonclick="Something">
   Order One
  &lt;/DIV>
  &lt;DIV  myonclick="Something">
   Order Two
  &lt;/DIV>
 &lt;/div>
```

Comment: Please organize your question

Comment: I have tried Tried Action builder and JS executor still not able to click.  Please help .

Answer (score 0):

try to click via JS without make the element visible

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Comment: I have tried this, this neither clicks the element not results in error.